# Unit Testing Case Statements

Tags: tdd, tsqlt

I appreciate this probably isn't the place to ask, if there is a better place please let me know.

I have a legacy Stored Procedure that selects some data and inserts into a table.  However there are quite a few case statements that I would like to test and I wondered how that should be done.

```
insert into [dbo].[utb_ITP]
...
case when [sme].[Reporting Countries] = 'Multiple Countries'
     then 'United Kingdom-Multiple Countries'
     when patindex('%-$',[sme].[Reporting Countries) > 1
     then left([sme].[Reporting countries], (pat index('%-%', [sme].[Reporting Countries]) - 1 ))
     else [sme].[Reporting Countries]
end as [SVC_COUNTRY]
```

I think the samples I have seen have all been mocking data and testing functions, but I haven't really seen examples like a case statement.  Do I test the final output or the component parts? So I would first test

```
[sme].[Reporting Countries] = 'Multiple Countries'
     then 'United Kingdom-Multiple Countries'
```

In that I would use an AssertEqualsTable where the Expected value would be 'United Kingdom-Multiple Countries' and then the insert into the Actual would run the first part of the case, something like:

```
insert into #Expected values ('United Kingdom-Multiple Countries')

insert into #Actual
select case [sme].[Reporting Countries] = 'Multiple Countries'
            then 'United Kingdom-Multiple Countries'
end
from   [SourceTable] as [sme]
where [sme].[Reporting Countries] = 'Multiple Countries'

exec AssertEqualsTable ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You do want to isolate those branches of your `CASE` statement. That means you need to write one test for each possible branch within it.

You also want to isolate those tests from other functionality. That means, fake all tables involved and then insert just enough rows (likely 1 in these tests) to prove the point. `tSQLt.FakeTable` allows you to put data only in the columns that are relevant to testing this specific piece of functionality. In your case that looks like it might be just the `[sme].[Reporting Countries]` column.

So you want to write one test for `'Multiple Countries'`, two to test the `PATINDEX` (e.g. `'value-withdash'` and `'othervalue-withdash'`), and finally one for the `ELSE` branch (e.g. `'other value without dash'`).

In the tests, I tend to pay more attention to making sure the intent of the test is clear, than that the values are realistic.

If you have other case statements in that `INSERT`, write independent tests for those, following the same pattern.